# Proper way of changing scaffold content depending on orientation

Tags: dart, flutter, maps

I have a screen with GoogleMap widget and couple Text widgets. What I'm trying to do is to let map utilize whole screen in landscape orientation without AppBar, while being restricted to Container size in portrait orientaion.

Now I just have 2 scaffold widgets which beign redrawn on each orientaion change, and after couple rotations whole device freezes and I have to reboot it.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
if (mediaQueryData.orientation == Orientation.landscape) {
  return Scaffold(
    body:GoogleMap(
            ...
          ),
  );
}
else{
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Title'),
    ),
    body: ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Text'),
        Text('Text'),
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/3,
          child: GoogleMap(
            ...
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

So I would really appreciate if someone could guide me to more efficient way of doing something like this.

Also if there's not, I would also like to know if it's possible to have working gestures (scroll, pan, etc.) in GoogleMap widget nested in scrollable ListView.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone intrested someone suggested this method, but comment got deleted:
 
`Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final isLandScape = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape;
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: isLandScape ? null : AppBar(
          title: Text('Title'),
        ),`
I used same method also for Visibility widget that includes other widgets besides map:

```
 visible: isLandScape ? false : true,
```

And same for Container with map:

```
Container(
          height: isLandScape ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/3,
          child: GoogleMap(
            ///
          ),
        ),
```

Seems to be working stable now.